# What should I use for my website mobile version ?jquery mobile / CSS3 page media / detecting browser size by jscript or redirecting to new page?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-mobile

I have an personal profile website at http://www.kaidul.web44.net/ and I have used jquery, flash & high interactive component in it. But developing a small device version of it is becoming a challenge for me.It's page structure is based on jquery. I am now in fix in what should I approach ?
( jquery mobile / CSS3 page media / detecting browser size by jscript or redirecting to new page or anything else )

You can recommend me about it's structure whether I should modify it or not.

please help me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My opinion is that you should do a redirect to a new page... because.. in the future you might want to modify something and will be difficult.. and another reason.. because is another view... Almost everybody is doing in a subdomain... and if the user want to view the desktop version... even if he is mobile.. redirect him to the large view...